# Iterate images to download in order in React.js using map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, download, frontend, display

I'm making a photography website as a blog, and I am displaying each image down to another. However, each image is in low resolution for better performance, and I want the user to be able to download the full resolution.

The thing is that I am using map() to display each image. I tried using a map() again inside the map() that displays the images to get the button below each photo, but it only allows me to download the first image in my object for all the buttons. So, I want it to make it in order.

Please help

**Here is the code**

```
import { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from "react";
import Aos from "aos";
import "aos/dist/aos.css";
import animations from "./data/animations";
import images from "./data/images";
import { BiGridAlt } from "react-icons/bi";
import { LazyLoadImage } from "react-lazy-load-image-component";
import fullSizeImgs from "./data/fullSizeImgs";

function Pictures(props) {
  const [fullSizeIndx, setFullSizeIndx] = useState([props.id]);

  console.log(fullSizeImgs);


  const getImgsInOrder = (e) => {
    fullSizeImgs.forEach((index, arrayImg) => {
      if (index === arrayImg.length) {
        return fullSizeImgs[arrayImg].fullImg;
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <button
        className="navbar"
      >
        <BiGridAlt size="40px" stroke="20px" className="icon" color="black" />
      </button>
      <div>
        {fullSizeImgs.map((img) => (
          <div>
            {!gridIsActive ? (
              <div>
                {images.map((image) => (
                  <div>
                    <h1 className="title-no-grid">{image.title}</h1>
                    <LazyLoadImage
                      key={image.id}
                      className="picture-img"
                      src={image.image}
                      alt="nature1"
                    />
                    <div className="full-size-box">
                      <a href={img.fullImg} download className="full-size">
                        Click to Download Full Resolution
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div className="grid-container">
              
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default Pictures;
```

It is well seen that I took the fullSizeImg object outside the first map() to be able to display each one below each image, but I cannot get the pictures in order. Only the first one with id: 0

Comment: Does `fullSizeImgs` and `images` have a 1-to-1 mapping? In other words, if there are 5 images, say A, B, E, D, C in `fullSizeImgs` - then does `images` also have the same images in the same order (with lower resolution, of course)?

Comment: If "yes" (to my previous comment), then you need only one loop. Try something like this: `fullSizeImgs.map((fullSzImg, idx) => (<div>...<LazyLoadImage .... src={images[idx].image}></LazyLoadImage><div><a href={fullSzIm.fullImg}...></a></div></div>));`

Comment: I tried that way just now, but it doesn't allow me to click the <a> tag as a button

Comment: Don't think that changing the looping would normally impact clickability of a-href. Was it working earlier?